# nginx: what is nodelay in http request limit module?

Tags: nginx

I am learning nginx httprequestlimitmodule. i am not getting the concept of nodelay in httprequestmodule. i have tried below two configuration with nodelay and without nodelay. in both cases with nodelay and without nodelay i am hitting 10 request in 1 seconds and getting 503 temporary service unavailable error for 6 requests and 4 requests are successful. my question is if the result is same with nodelay and without nodelay then what is the use of nodelay option here.

```
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=2r/s;
limit_req zone=one burst=2 nodelay;
```

---

```
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=2r/s;
limit_req zone=one burst=2 ;
```

Comment: Look at the time of last successful request.

Comment: can you please explain it in brief.

Comment: Check my new answer here https://serverfault.com/a/984020/485927

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take this config:

```
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=1r/s;

server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:81;

    location / {
        limit_req zone=one burst=5;
        echo 'OK';
    }

    location /nodelay {
        limit_req zone=one burst=5 nodelay;
        echo 'OK';
    }
}
```

and test it with nodelay

```
$ siege -q -b -r 1 -c 10 http://127.0.0.1:81/nodelay
      done.

Transactions:                  6 hits
Availability:              60.00 %
Elapsed time:               0.01 secs
Data transferred:           0.00 MB
Response time:              0.00 secs
Transaction rate:         600.00 trans/sec
Throughput:             0.09 MB/sec
Concurrency:                0.00
Successful transactions:           6
Failed transactions:               4
Longest transaction:            0.00
Shortest transaction:           0.00
```

and without nodelay

```
$ siege -q -b -r 1 -c 10 http://127.0.0.1:81/
      done.

Transactions:                  6 hits
Availability:              60.00 %
Elapsed time:               5.00 secs
Data transferred:           0.00 MB
Response time:              2.50 secs
Transaction rate:           1.20 trans/sec
Throughput:             0.00 MB/sec
Concurrency:                3.00
Successful transactions:           6
Failed transactions:               4
Longest transaction:            5.00
Shortest transaction:           0.00
```

They both passed 6 request, buy with `nodelay` nginx process all *burst* requests instantly and without this option nginx makes excessive requests **to wait** so that overall rate would be no more than 1 request per second and last successful request took 5 seconds to complete.

EDIT: `rate=6r/s` actually means one request in 1/6th of a second. So if you send 6 request simultaneously you'll get 5 of them with 503.

There is a good answer with “bucket” explanation https://serverfault.com/a/247302/211028

Comment: what is the difference between  limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=1r/s;
 limit_req zone=one busts 5 nodelay and  limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=6r/s;
 limit_req zone=one

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: **The nodelay option is useful if you want to impose a rate limit without constraining the allowed spacing between requests.**

There's new documentation from Nginx with examples that answers this: https://www.nginx.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/

Here's the pertinent part.  Given:

```
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=mylimit:10m rate=10r/s;

location /login/ {
  limit_req zone=mylimit burst=20;
  ...
}
```

> The burst parameter defines how many requests a client can make in
>   excess of the rate specified by the zone (with our sample mylimit
>   zone, the rate limit is 10 requests per second, or 1 every 100
>   milliseconds). A request that arrives sooner than 100 milliseconds
>   after the previous one is put in a queue, and here we are setting the
>   queue size to 20.
>
> That means if 21 requests arrive from a given IP address
>   simultaneously, NGINX forwards the first one to the upstream server
>   group immediately and puts the remaining 20 in the queue. It then
>   forwards a queued request every 100 milliseconds, and returns 503 to
>   the client only if an incoming request makes the number of queued
>   requests go over 20.

If you add nodelay:

```
location /login/ {
  limit_req zone=mylimit burst=20 nodelay;
  ...
}
```

> With the nodelay parameter, NGINX still allocates slots in the queue
>   according to the burst parameter and imposes the configured rate
>   limit, but not by spacing out the forwarding of queued requests.
>   Instead, when a request arrives “too soon”, NGINX forwards it
>   immediately as long as there is a slot available for it in the queue.
>   It marks that slot as “taken” and does not free it for use by another
>   request until the appropriate time has passed (in our example, after
>   100 milliseconds).