# Nginx limit_req not blocking all excessive requests

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, rate-limiting

I want to block excessive requests on a per-IP basis, allowing at maxium 12 requests per second. For this sake, I have the following in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

http {

```
    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    ...

    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=perip:10m rate=12r/s;
    server {
        listen 80;
        location / {
            limit_req zone=perip nodelay;
        }
    }
```

Now, when I'm running the command `ab -k -c 100 -n 900 'https://www.mywebsite.com/'` in the terminal, I get the output with only 179 non-2xx responses out of 900.

Why isn't Nginx blocking most requests?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36642439/973254):

> with `nodelay` `nginx` process all burst requests instantly and without
> this option `nginx` makes excessive requests to wait so that overall
> rate would be no more than 1 request per second and last successful
> request took 5 seconds to complete.

> rate=6r/s actually means one request in 1/6th of a second. So if
> you send 6 request simultaneously you'll get 5 of them with 503

The problem might be in your testing method (or your expectations from it).

Comment: I do not use any burst, therefore nodelay should block any further requests I suppose.

Comment: @Edmond, from nginx docs: `If delaying of excessive requests while requests are being limited is not desired, the parameter nodelay should be used`, so you having opposite from `nodelay`, nginx continues to handle your excessive requests with `nodelay` option. If you does not want to, just change `nodelay` to `delay` without parameters (by default it is zero)